# compare value across sheets and select the first value of a different column when the condition is met

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, filter, match, vlookup

I have two sheets the first is a data entry, the second creates a column of unique dates from the first sheet (this I have working). Next, I want to get the value in the first sheet where it matches the date in the second sheet. the problem is it returns multiple values and I only want the first for each date row matched.

here is a Google sheet example  [Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hFiSoZid0k5nZ_UGkwQBktPMJ5rgUyphoclfQu15Bfo/edit?usp=sharing) in it sheet2 column B is what I'm looking to achieve.

on sheet2 I pull the dates from sheet1 using`=SORT(UNIQUE(Flatten(Sheet1!A5:A)))` this works.

Next, I want to take each date on sheet2 and get the row's first occurrence from sheet1 where the data matches and display the value in sheet1 column M in Sheet2 column B on the row where the date matches.

the example sheet hopefully makes it clearer!

my closest attempt was `=IF('Sheet1'!$A$5:A = A1, 'Sheet1'!M5,"")` but this doesn't work!

Sheet1
[image]

Sheet2

[image]

Comment: Did you try `VLOOKUP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=SORTN({Sheet1!A5:A, Sheet1!M5:M}, 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]

```
9^9   return all rows
2     group by
1     first column
1     in ascending order
```

Comment: that's great thank you! what is the "9^9, 2, 1, 1" ?